# state Warning Validation (CSS 4.0): "rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4)" is not a valid value for the "border" property

Tags: css, asp.net-core

I am finishing up my asp core 3 project and fixing some warning that occurred,but i cannot find the reason for this one?the css property works completely fine adding some transparency to the black border.What causes the warning? 
PS:My IDE is Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RGBa (Red = 0, Green = 0, Blue = 0, Alpha = 0.4)
it's different from `rgb(0, 0, 0)`

for border short hand:
`border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)`

Answer (score 2):

The `rgb()` syntax expects only three values. To include the fourth alpha value, you should use [`rgba()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Examples) instead.